# View and access DOM Explorer code in excel vba

Tags: javascript, html, excel, internet-explorer, dom

I am trying to abstract HTML code from a website in Internet Explorer and use it in excel by excel VBA. The code is shown in source code is different to the one I view in DOM explorer.

As some of you said, it is hard to comprehend with code image, maybe I post the abstract HTML code down below. Due to the character limit in stack overflow, I cannot post all the HTML code, sorry.

This is the code I got with `IE.document.body.innerHTML`(which is same as the one shown in source code)

`<tbody class="resizeTable__body"></tbody>`

But what I want is the code down below. (which is same as the one shown in dom explorer)

```
<tbody class="resizeTable__body"><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__group"><th class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__col--th resizeTable__group__col" colspan="4">2020</th></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">15 Aug</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$482.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">03 Jun - 02 Jul</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">30 Jul</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">03 Jun - 02 Jul</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$482.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            <a class="font-l d-print-none view--20200730000000" href="/Service/ServiceGetBillingPdfFile.ashx?caNo=68843035104&amp;Filename=18754820149.pdf&amp;bfIndicator=&amp;tranDate=20200730000000" target="_blank">View</a>
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">06 May - 02 Jun</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">29 Jun</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">06 May - 02 Jun</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$835.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            <a class="font-l d-print-none view--20200629000000" href="/Service/ServiceGetBillingPdfFile.ashx?caNo=68843035104&amp;Filename=19868460227.pdf&amp;bfIndicator=&amp;tranDate=20200629000000" target="_blank">View</a>
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">15 Jun</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$165.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">02 Apr - 05 May</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">28 May</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">02 Apr - 05 May</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$165.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            <a class="font-l d-print-none view--20200528000000" href="/Service/ServiceGetBillingPdfFile.ashx?caNo=68843035104&amp;Filename=10169653696.pdf&amp;bfIndicator=&amp;tranDate=20200528000000" target="_blank">View</a>
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">04 Feb - 03 Mar</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">30 Mar</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">04 Feb - 03 Mar</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$543.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            <a class="font-l d-print-none view--20200330000000" href="/Service/ServiceGetBillingPdfFile.ashx?caNo=68843035104&amp;Filename=19948328251.pdf&amp;bfIndicator=&amp;tranDate=20200330000000" target="_blank">View</a>
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">16 Mar</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$485.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">01 Jan - 03 Feb</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">27 Feb</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">01 Jan - 03 Feb</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$485.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            <a class="font-l d-print-none view--20200227000000" href="/Service/ServiceGetBillingPdfFile.ashx?caNo=68843035104&amp;Filename=18754703653.pdf&amp;bfIndicator=&amp;tranDate=20200227000000" target="_blank">View</a>
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">15 Feb</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$395.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">30 Nov - 31 Dec</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">30 Jan</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">30 Nov - 31 Dec</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$395.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            <a class="font-l d-print-none view--20200130000000" href="/Service/ServiceGetBillingPdfFile.ashx?caNo=68843035104&amp;Filename=12816959762.pdf&amp;bfIndicator=&amp;tranDate=20200130000000" target="_blank">View</a>
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">15 Jan</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$511.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__group"><th class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__col--th resizeTable__group__col" colspan="4">2019</th></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">02 Nov - 29 Nov</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">30 Dec</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">02 Nov - 29 Nov</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$511.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            <a class="font-l d-print-none view--20191230000000" href="/Service/ServiceGetBillingPdfFile.ashx?caNo=68843035104&amp;Filename=13441911409.pdf&amp;bfIndicator=&amp;tranDate=20191230000000" target="_blank">View</a>
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">16 Dec</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$896.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">01 Oct - 01 Nov</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">28 Nov</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">01 Oct - 01 Nov</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$896.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            <a class="font-l d-print-none view--20191128000000" href="/Service/ServiceGetBillingPdfFile.ashx?caNo=68843035104&amp;Filename=16879666474.pdf&amp;bfIndicator=&amp;tranDate=20191128000000" target="_blank">View</a>
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">15 Nov</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$1,243.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">01 Sep - 30 Sep</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">30 Oct</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">01 Sep - 30 Sep</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$1,243.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            <a class="font-l d-print-none view--20191030000000" href="/Service/ServiceGetBillingPdfFile.ashx?caNo=68843035104&amp;Filename=18284515211.pdf&amp;bfIndicator=&amp;tranDate=20191030000000" target="_blank">View</a>
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">15 Oct</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$1,301.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">01 Aug - 31 Aug</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">28 Sep</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">01 Aug - 31 Aug</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$1,301.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            <a class="font-l d-print-none view--20190928000000" href="/Service/ServiceGetBillingPdfFile.ashx?caNo=68843035104&amp;Filename=14379668674.pdf&amp;bfIndicator=&amp;tranDate=20190928000000" target="_blank">View</a>
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">16 Sep</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$1,459.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">03 Jul - 31 Jul</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">29 Aug</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">03 Jul - 31 Jul</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$1,459.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            <a class="font-l d-print-none view--20190829000000" href="/Service/ServiceGetBillingPdfFile.ashx?caNo=68843035104&amp;Filename=10629821442.pdf&amp;bfIndicator=&amp;tranDate=20190829000000" target="_blank">View</a>
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">15 Aug</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$1,606.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">30 May - 02 Jul</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">30 Jul</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">30 May - 02 Jul</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$1,606.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            <a class="font-l d-print-none view--20190730000000" href="/Service/ServiceGetBillingPdfFile.ashx?caNo=68843035104&amp;Filename=10209446397.pdf&amp;bfIndicator=&amp;tranDate=20190730000000" target="_blank">View</a>
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">15 Jul</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Payment:</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">Direct Debit</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$1,055.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            
            </td>
            </tr><tr class="resizeTable__row resizeTable__title resizeTable__title--generation resizeTable-show--xs"><td class="resizeTable__col resizeTable__title__col" colspan="4">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">03 May - 29 May</span -->
            </td></tr><tr class="resizeTable__row">
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">27 Jun</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-hide--xs resizeTable-data--xs">
                <span class="d-inline-block">Bill</span>
                <span class="d-inline-block"></span>
                <!-- span class="d-inline-block">03 May - 29 May</span -->
            </td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle resizeTable-data--xs">$1,055.00</td>
            <td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            <a class="font-l d-print-none view--20190627000000" href="/Service/ServiceGetBillingPdfFile.ashx?caNo=68843035104&amp;Filename=14066798372.pdf&amp;bfIndicator=&amp;tranDate=20190627000000" target="_blank">View</a>
            </td>
            </tr></tbody>
```

You can see there is additional code in the DOM Explorer one (the content of `<tbody>` ), but `IE.document.body.innerHTML` can only get the source code one. Are there any ways to get the code in DOM Explorer?

Comment: Please post code, not images of code.

Comment: IE.document.body.innerHTML should return the source code. I want to confirm with you what result exactly you are getting by running this code? what you are showing is the table body tag. Are those data generated dynamically? If possible please provide any sample HTML code to test the issue. If the site is public then you can also try to share the site address. It can help us to test the issue.

Comment: As there are around 400 line of code in the body tag of the source code or DOM Explorer and the website can only be accessed after log in so it is hard to show it in here, sorry about that.

Comment: But i found any similar situation in other web, maybe I can share it here.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, reply to your question, those data is generated dynamically, in this way, could I still get it?

Comment: When I try to test with your HTML code then I found that I get that full HTML as source code. So I am not able to produce the issue with that code. If possible can you try to develop a sample and share it with us that can help to reproduce the issue? It can really help to understand the issue and we can try to provide suggestions for it.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Do you mean you get full HTML the same as the one in DOM explorer, as the version in DOM is different from the one in source code, and I do not know how to get the dom version one.

Comment: Yes, I get the full code that is inside the body tag. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/VAM4dMl).

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Could you show me your full subroutine of the VBA, maybe I type something wrong my sub. Thanks

Comment: This is the test code. [See here](https://justpaste.it/6yxmi).

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, I have tried your code, still not work and I have posted some of my code here( as it nearly above the character limited, I cannot post all), let see could you solve my problem, thanks

Comment: I made a test with your updated code and it worked fine. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/TCVMnxz) Please inform is which exact version of the IE browser and OS build you are using for making this test? If possible try to make a test on any other machine to check whether issue is reproducible or not on other machines.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I am using IE11 (version:11.1610.17134.0) and the OS is windows 10, is it similar to yours? by the way, I find some related terms for this question, as the code I want to get is dynamic HTML code, could I still do it with ```IE.document.body.innerHTML```?

Comment: I am using Win 10, IE 11.836.18362.0 version. For dynamic content, I am not sure whether it is accessible. We need the site to make a test to find whether data is accessible or not. It also depends upon a site on how it was developed.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Maybe I could u the website for testing but it is a bit complicated, as it needs to log in to get the page and the code I want. Could you give your email address so I could give you more information or do you know how to have a private chat in stack overflow as I am a newbie here. Thanks!

Comment: I thought that site is public. I understand that site required login to access that page to make a test. To protect the user's privacy we are not allowed to take any confidential information. I will try to search for any VBA IE automation example to fetch data from the dynamic table and try to provide you. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thank you so much!!! Just post it here if you find any example or solution related.

Comment: @ChrisG I have change image to code, let see whether you know how to solve it. For clarification, the code I want to get is dynamic HTML, is there a way do it?

Comment: I can see that you want to access the data from the 'tbody' tag and you had shared the HTML code that is receded in the tbody tag. I suggest trying to share the HTML code of that table. So that we can see whether there is any way to access that table. It may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT What do you mean by that table? Actually I want to get the of the <a> tag inside the <tbody>,for example  ```<td class="resizeTable__col align-middle text-right resizeTable-data--xs">
            <a class="font-l d-print-none view--20200730000000" href="/Service/ServiceGetBillingPdfFile.ashx?caNo=68843035104&amp;Filename=18754820149.pdf&amp;bfIndicator=&amp;tranDate=20200730000000" target="_blank">View</a>
            </td>```, but it was not shown when I use ```innerHTML```. Is this the that table you want?

Comment: no, tbody tag should be within a table. Try to share the code of that table that contains the tbody. Check whether that table has any ID or Name. Try to access the desired data with the help of that table to see this approach is working or not.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT As the code in there is above the maximum character of this post, I post the image of the code here [link](https://imgur.com/a/mR23sEA)

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT There are id in the table, but will that id help me access the code inside  ```<tbody>```?

Comment: Does the example I shared for reading the table data worked for you? If yes, you can mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) If you have any further questions, please let us know about it. We will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I try to create a web page that can generate the data in a table dynamically. Then I try to fetch that data using VBA IE Automation.

Sample VBA code:

```
Sub demo()

    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim hTable, hBody, hTR, hTD, ws As Object
    Dim ii, y, z As Integer
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
   
    IE.Visible = True
 
  
    URL = "----your URL here---------"
 
    IE.navigate URL
 
    
    Do While IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
 
     Set hTable = IE.document.getElementById("myTableData")
    ii = 1
    z = 1
        
            Set hBody = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
            For Each bb In hBody
                Set hTR = bb.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                For Each Tr In hTR
                    Set hTD = Tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                    y = 1
                    For Each Td In hTD
                        ws.Cells(z, y).Value = Td.innerText
                        y = y + 1
                    Next Td
                    DoEvents
                    z = z + 1
                Next Tr
                Exit For
            Next bb
                     
    Set IE = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

This is just a sample code. further, you can try to modify this sample as per your own requirements and try to fetch the desired data.